# Xamarin XAML Conditional Styling

Tags: xaml, xamarin, styles, conditional-statements, datatrigger

I have a `StackLayout` in a `ListView` that I want to hide (`IsVisible="false"`) based on whether the object has a `PerformedDate` value or not (defaulted to `null`).

Right now, I'm trying to use `DataTriggers` on the `StackLayout` using a `label`'s text as an indicator for whether or not the object has a `PerformedDate`:

```
<Label x:Name="PerformedDateLabel" Text="{Binding PerformedDate}" IsVisible="True"/>
<StackLayout Padding="0, 25, 0, 0" Spacing="0">
    <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd}'}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:MMM}'}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <StackLayout.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference PerformedDateLabel}, Path=Text}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </StackLayout.Triggers>
</StackLayout>
```

It doesn't hidee the `StackLayout` when a `PerformedDate` exists.
Any ideas?

I've also tried the `Path=Text.Length` `Value="0"` approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an additonal Property `HasPerformedDate`

**C#**

```C#
public DateTime? PerformedDate
{
    get { return _performedDate; }
    set
    {
        _performedDate = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasPerformedDate));
    }
}

public bool HasPerformedDate => PerformedDate.HasValue;
```

**Xaml**

```XAML
<Label x:Name="PerformedDateLabel" Text="{Binding PerformedDate}" IsVisible="True"/>
<StackLayout Padding="0, 25, 0, 0" Spacing="0" IsVisible="{Binding HasPerformedDate}">
  <Label Text="{Binding PerformedDate, StringFormat='{0:dd}'}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
  <Label Text="{Binding PerformedDate, StringFormat='{0:MMM}'}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: ahh yes, i too have thought about this way, didn't know if my project requirements would allow me changing the object by adding additional properties specifically for view purposes. if i end up doing it this way, i'll accept. thanks for your input :]